# current location on google maps without turning GPS on (android device)?

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it possible for google maps to show my approximate location on maps without turning GPS on on my device?  I understand it can not be very accurate but I am fine with that (even if shows location within a radios of 2km).  I am having version 9.72.2 of google maps on my android device.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have Internet access, it's possible via [Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro?hl=en) and information about nearest mobile operator cell or/and wifi access points 
You need send requests like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

with information about target [Cell Tower](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro?hl=en#cell_tower_object) (how to get LAC and CID you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31020866/6950238)) or [WiFi access point](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#wifi_access_point_object) in request, and if target WiFi access point is in Google database your got [response JSON](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#responses) with Lat/Lon and accuracy.

NB! But sometimes it returns completely wrong results.

For show current position you need to disable "standard" MyLocation tool

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
```

and use custom, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14826345/6950238).